# Machine Learning using GPGPU

Tags: cuda, machine-learning, gpgpu

Are there any libraries or frameworks available for machine learning, especially for processing of huge data in GPGPU environemnts like CUDA ?

Comment: I don't know if there's a general frameworks. But I know OpenCV's **softcascade** have a CUDA version implemented.

Comment: Is there a specific class of machine learning algorithms that you are looking for? I have read many papers for neural networks and genetic programming, all of them were using specific and handmade implementations. CUDA is not the jack of all trades and one has to tailor it to suit their needs :-)

Comment: SVM and linear regression @M2X

Comment: @AmrithKrishna As far as I know, there are no frameworks for SVMs. If there was one, I would have remembered when I was doing a literature review for my thesis. However, don't just take my word for it.

Comment: You may find this link interesting: http://fastml.com/running-things-on-a-gpu/

Comment: Have a look at OpenCV. I think the GPU module's HOG descriptor can be configured to use SVM. [Check this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-setsvmdetector).